# Storing in Array from methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods, input

im trying to a double in an array. The question is that i have to store the results from the user input in the array. For example, i ask the user for the initial population, first day and increase rate. Then calculate the increase in population. I am meant to store that increase in population in an array, can anyone help? stuck.
heres my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kd = new Scanner(System.in);


    double tempPop, tempRate;
    int tempDay;
    double growth;
    System.out.println("Enter Population: ");
    tempPop = kd.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter Days: ");
    tempDay = kd.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter Rate: ");
    tempRate = kd.nextDouble();


    final double SCORES = tempDay;
    double scores [] = new double[(int) SCORES];

    for(int i = 0; i < SCORES; i++)
    {
        scores[i] = getRate(tempPop, tempDay, tempRate);
        System.out.println(scores[i]);
    }




}
public static double getRate(double tempPop, int tempDay, double tempRate)
{
    double popul, pops = 0;
    for (double day = 0; day <= tempDay; day++)
    {
        popul = tempPop + (tempPop * tempRate/100);

        pops = day*popul;

    }
    return pops;
}
```

}

This is my output: (only example)

```
Enter Population: 
10
Enter Days: 
2
Enter Rate: 
3

10.3
10.3
```

Comment: What's not working with your code?

Comment: `final double SCORES = tempDay;double scores [] = new double[(int) SCORES];` Why don't use `double scores [] = new double[tempDay]` directly? Your question is also unclear, where/when do you have the error and what error you got?

Comment: sorry, i just edited it. i get two 10.3's, its not storing all the different values, its just storing the last value over and over again.

Comment: You're calling the getRate method for as many times as the SCORES for loop runs for, without changing the input parameters (which is why it's outputting the same answer multiple times.

Comment: isnt that how i am meant to store the calculated values in the array? @AndrewMartin

Comment: The problem is that you read the values in once, then call the getRate method using those values. The loop runs twice, but both times it calls the getRate method with the exact same parameters, meaning it will get the exact same double value back.

Comment: how would i go about fixing that? i think i know what you mean but im still really confused. @AndrewMartin

Comment: @user2291452: Check my answer, is that what you want?

Comment: Why do you declare your indexes as `double`? In the for loop in `getRate`, shouldn't it be `for(int day=0; ...` ?

Comment: that doesnt really make a difference, int and double are the same thing if your input is in int @rath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? Rather than passing the value of tempDay into the loop, which never changes, you pass the value of i in instead (which increases until the tempDay value is met).

```
double scores [] = new double[tempDay];
for(int i = 0; i < tempDay; i++) {
    scores[i] = getRate(tempPop, i + 1, tempRate);
    System.out.println(scores[i]);
}
```

This way, with the following sample data, the output would be:

```
Enter Population: 
10
Enter Days: 
2
Enter Rate: 
3
10.3
20.6
```

Comment: yes thats it, im still confused but seeing what to do has cleared things up, thanks for your help.

Comment: You read the three parameters at the start and then inside the for loop passed them to the getRate method. However, each time the for loop iterated it called the same getRate method with the same parameters, without ever changing them. This meant the method always returned the same result. In my answer, I sent i + 1 instead of tempDay. This sent the same population and rate each time, but changed the day being sent so a pattern could be shown. I sent i + 1, as days obviously start from 1 and not 0.

Comment: I edited my answer to show what my input values were. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: oh i get it! every time i said day was 2, it just kept running 2 over and over again

Comment: yeh all that helps, will keep in mind for next time. have my test tomorrow so like really stressed! trying to revise everything

Comment: Exactly. Simple mistake. If you'd entered the day as 5, the for loop would have run 5 times and given you the same answer 5 times. (Good luck in your exam!)

Answer (score 0):

You are reading `tempPop`, `tempDay`, `tempRate` once and never change them. So the return value of `getRate` in the loop will always be the same.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve but I think you have to change at least one of the parameter depending on the previous calculation in the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of `final double SCORES` and use `tempDay` directly for the size of `scores` and the stop parameter in your `for` loop.